# mysql query extract count using case statement

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table with following attributes

premises_name, visit_date

each premises can be visited more than once in different dates. i want a report which shows that how many premises visited once, twice, three times, four time like below

```
+------------------------+
| no. of premises  count |
+------------------------+
| 135              1     |
| 200              2     |
| 90               3     |
+------------------------+
```

first row means there are 135 premises which have been visited one time.

regards,

Comment: Can you provide your code as it currently stands?

Comment: can a premise be visited more than once in same date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a query like this:

```
SELECT cnt no_of_premises, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT count(*) cnt
    FROM premises
    GROUP BY premises_name) s
GROUP BY cnt
```